# Doublely Linked Lists remove()

Tags: c++

I have recently was trying to brush up on c++ so some of the syntactical errors could be in front of my face, but I seem to be getting ERROR: C2440 when trying to run my code below. It breaks on the first line of main and points to line :122

Specifically this line: 
Node* target_node = find_node_by_data(info);

Error C2440 'Initializing': cannot convert from void to Doublely_Linked_list::Node *'

Thanks for stopping by and helping me with this issue.

```
template<typename AnyType>
void Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::find_node_by_data(AnyType const& information)const {
Node* current = head;

while (current) {
    if (current->information == information) {
        return current;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
return nullptr;
}


template<typename AnyType>
void Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::unlinkData(Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::Node* n) {
if (n->prev) {
    n->prev->next = n->next;
}
else {
    head = n->next;
    head->prev = nullptr;
}

if (n->next) {
    n->next->prev = n->prev;
}
else {
    tail = n->prev;
    tail->next = nullptr;
}
}


template<typename AnyType>
void Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::remove(AnyType info) {
Node* target_node = find_node_by_data(info);

if (target_node) {
    unlinkData(target_node);
    delete target_node;
}
}

int main() {
Doublely_Linked_list<double> list1;
double temp;
const double info = 2.1;
while (1)
{
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp == -1) break;
    else
    {
        list1.insertAtHead(temp);
    }
}
cout << list1;
list1.remove(info);
cout << list1;
}
```

In the console where I populate the node with values, I wanted to populate the node value of '2.1' and have it removed it after I am done populating the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty obvious, `find_node_by_data` is declared as returning `void`

```
template<typename AnyType>
void Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::find_node_by_data(AnyType const& information)const {
^^^^
```

when clearly it should be returning a node pointer

```
template<typename AnyType>
Node* Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::find_node_by_data(AnyType const& information)const {
^^^^^
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try to implement this I get a few more errors to occur. I get A type qualifier is not allowed in a non-member function, Node is undefined, and template argument list must match the parameter list. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really, not without seeing all your code and knowing what lines of code those error messages belong to. I mean `Node` isn't defined in the code you've posted. I assumed you'd defined it somewhere though.

Comment: I have the paste bin above with my full project to show how I use the Node class. My interpretation of this problem seems to be HOW I access the Node* return type for when I change the function from void to Node* Thanks for taking the time to help me figure this out. Much appreciated

Comment: @SpencerKoss Well your `Node` class is Inside your `Doublely_Linked_list` class. So anywhere that context isn't implicit (which includes return types of functions) you need to be explicit  `Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::Node*` But inside the body of a `Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>` method that context is already implied, so in that case you don't have to qualify the `Node` name. If that's not clear I'll add more detail to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help John, I have finally fixed it after some time away from the Computer. 
 My solution for the function is:

```
template<typename AnyType>
typename Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::Node* 
Doublely_Linked_list<AnyType>::find_node_by_data(AnyType const& information)const {
Node* current = head;

while (current) {
    if (current->data == information) {
        return current;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
return nullptr;
}
```